# XSLT: get relative URI instead of absolute uri

Tags: xslt, dita

I want to:

1. Create a file in the same folder where I am running my XSLT stylesheet against.
2. This new file has a list of href to files with a certain value in the copyrholder element.
3. Have a relative path in the href.

This is what I currently have:

1. I create a new topic in the same folder
2. List of href with absolute uri

Problem: make the absolute path relative to file I just created.

**Example**

This is the folder I am referencing to and all files have that particular element I want in the list:

C:/dita/file1.dita

C:/dita/file2.dita

C:/dita/file3.dita

C:/dita/file4.dita

C:/dita/en/file5.dita

This is the XSLT I use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:result-document href="newtopic.dita" doctype-public="-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" doctype-system="topic.dtd" indent="yes">
<topic id="to_new_topics">
<xsl:element name="title">New topics</xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="body">
<xsl:variable name="folderURI" select="resolve-uri('.',base-uri())"/>
<ul>
<xsl:for-each select="collection(concat($folderURI, '?select=*.dita;recurse=yes'))//copyrholder[contains(., 'value')]">
<li>
<xsl:element name="xref">
<xsl:attribute name="href">
<xsl:value-of select="base-uri()" />
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
</li>
</xsl:for-each>
</ul>
</xsl:element>
</topic>
</xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the current result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="to_new_topics">
   <title>New topics</title>
   <body>
      <ul>
         <li><xref href="file:/C:/´dita/file1.dita"/></li>
         <li><xref href="file:/C:/´dita/file2.dita"/></li>
         <li><xref href="file:/C:/´dita/file3.dita"/></li>
         <li><xref href="file:/C:/´dita/file4.dita"/></li>
         <li><xref href="file:/C:/dita/en/file5.dita"/></li>
      </ul>
   </body>            
</topic>
```

This what I would like to have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="to_new_topics">
   <title>New topics</title>
   <body>
      <ul>
         <li><xref href="file1.dita"/></li>
         <li><xref href="file2.dita"/></li>
         <li><xref href="file3.dita"/></li>
         <li><xref href="file4.dita"/></li>
         <li><xref href="en/file5.dita"/></li>
      </ul>
   </body>            
</topic>
```

Anyone whou can help me to make the path relative?

Comment: Would `replace(base-uri(), '^' || $folderURI || '/', '')` instead of `base-uri()` work? Or just `substring-after(base-uri(), $folderURI || '/')`? (The `||` operator is XPath 3 so you might need `replace(base-uri(), concat('^', $folderURI, /'), '')` instead in XSLT 2.

Comment: I changed it like this: `<xsl:value-of select="replace(base-uri(), '^' || base-uri() || '/', '')" />` but it gives me the same result as the original one.

Comment: I don't see how your variant would make any sense, if the first argument to `replace` is e.g. `file:///C:/foo/bar.xml'` and you then feed `^ `file:///C:/foo/bar.xml/` as the second argument it is obviously never found and not replaced. I thought in your XSLT with `<xsl:variable name="folderURI" select="resolve-uri('.',base-uri())"/>` you get something like `file:///C:/bar` and you could use that to replace the initial part in the URIs you construct later on ofr the `href` attribute.

Comment: But it is hard imagining the exact values of URIs, perhaps run some test of `$folderURI` and see whether you can strip some part (e.g. `string-join(tokenize($folderURI, '/')[position() != last()], '/')`) and then use that to replace the common part in the URIs of the `href` attributes.

Comment: I am sorry, I used this one: `<xsl:value-of select="replace(base-uri(), '^' || $folderURI || '/', '')" />`.  Previous one makes no sense indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this work:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(base-uri(), $folderURI, '') "/>
```

(did not see this at the comments), since if the problem is the absolute path at the xref, replacing the path with empty value should solve this problem. Or I just understand something terrible wrong. :) This is my tests end result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="to_new_topics">
   <title>New topics</title>
   <body>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <xref href="en/file3.dita"/>
         </li>
         <li>
            <xref href="file1.dita"/>
         </li>
         <li>
            <xref href="file2.dita"/>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</topic>
```

Tested with: XSL, newtopic.xml (to avoid problems and renamed this .xml, not .dita) and all file*.dita files are in the same folder or subfolder.